# How do I delete a related object with a 1 to 1 relationship in the Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF Model First and in my `Employee` class I have a `Manager` property with a 1 to 1 relationship to itself, the `Employee` class:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {          
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I get an existing object from the database and change the manager with:

```
employee.Manager = otherEmployeeInstance;
Context.Entry(employee).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
Context.SaveChanges();
```

It works just fine; however, if I want to remove the manager this will not work:

```
employee.Manager = null;
```

It looks to me that I first need to "load" the manager (Employee) instance into the context since this makes it work:

```
var dummyVar = employee.Manager.Id;
employee.Manager = null;
```

So the question is, what's the best (proper) way to remove a related object?

Answer (score 2):

obviously, when you want to delete an entity of the one-to-one relationship, the EF doesn't allow to delete it without preparing it before. that is, removing any dependent entity information from that entity. Remember, we are using Relational Database system and any breaking relation without any coordination causes to anomaly and failure.
When you want to remove a relation, you can use this at your controller:

```
employee.Remove(Manager);//Automatically Removes Navigational Properties at both entities
db.SaveChanges();
```

Instead of this :

```
employee.Manager = null;
```

Comment: With model-first, VS2010 generates a POCO object. As you may see in my code, Employee does not have a remove method. Am I missing something else?

Comment: not a remote method. but any relationship between entities is considerable here. in this problem there is no differences between any design methods like model-first or code-first. make sure you have removed any dependent properties before deleting an entity.

Comment: What do you mean with "make sure you have removed any dependent properties before deleting an entity"? In my case I'd like to remove the relationship since an employee may not be the manager's subordinate anymore. However, I don't want to remove the "Manager" instance from the database.

Comment: In relational operations you need to remove a relation in correct way and complete manner. If you want to store previews states, so save the track of deleted relation or save it at other tables, maybe.